# Make an accesible Python server

Tags: networking, server, python, sockets

I'm using the Python library `socket` to create a program, and I want to be able to allow my friends to connect from their homes. I have the rest of the program running and it works great on the localhost and on a local network, but I want to be able to, like I said, let my friends connect.

My guess is that I would have to use my global [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address), and I can get that via [PySTUN](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pystun), but whenever I try to bind the socket/server thing to my global IP address it barfs back this error:

> socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address`

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: If you are in a private network (ie: behind a router) you will need to make the router redirect those external requests to your machine. Check your router settings. Binding the external address will not work.

Comment: When I start the server it says `Socket Created at 127.0.1.1 on port 5007` (I programmed it to get the IP the socket is bound to)

Comment: Bind it to `0.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your network correctly, basically. And you need to bind on the IP address of the external network interface (eth0 for example), not the local address on the local interface (lo). If you have a router, then your public address (the one assigned to your router) is not the address of your computer. You will have to bind locally, and tell the router to open up the port you wish to use, and forward all traffic through it, to your computer. You may be able to do that with UPnP/STUN, depending on your router, or you may need to manually configure it.